# How to call both C++ and C from Cython?

Tags: cython

I followed the directions (http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) to wrap a C++ library with cython.  Part of this is telling Cython to generate C++.  That worked nicely; so far so good.

But now, in my cython code, I need to call some C libraries.  Since Cython is generating C++, when I refer to the C library, it mangles the name, so it fails when it tries to link.

I would prefer not to recompile all my C code as C++.  Is there any way to get Cython to deal with both C and C++ at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried using `extern "C"`?